# SSAS Error. An unexpected error occurred: "A call to a COM component returned an error in the format HRESULT E_FAIL."

Tags: ssas, visual-studio-2022

I encountered an error in a SSAS project in Visual Studio 2022. I needed to add an average indicator function, for which I created a calculated element.

After execution I encounter the error linked below.

Screenshot of my calculated element:

[image]

Error messasge:

[image]

I thought that the problem could be because the names of the measures were not in English. But when I renamed them in English I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you translate the error you're getting to English?